# UWP: Setting focus on TeachingTip programatically

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have just converted all of the custom teaching tips in my UWP app to use the new muxc:TeachingTip control. They are working fine when using a mouse but you can't set focus on them so that the user can dismiss them using a keyboard or Xbox controller.

The code:

bool bFocusSuccess = myTT.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);

indicates that focus is successfully set but it is not.

Any suggestions?

Win10: 1909
Microsoft.UI.Xaml: 2.4.2

Comment: Hello, [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.focusmanager?view=winrt-19041#remarks) explains that `Popup` such as `TeachingTip` have independent focus scopes, and elements with logical focus may not necessarily get keyboard focus. Can you elaborate on the operation method of using keyboard or controller dismiss `TeachingTip`? `TeachingTip` has the `IsLightDismissEnabled` property for setting click on the blank space to close.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT - thank you for that document. The context is that when the app starts for the first time I display 6 teaching tips, and use the click event of the Action or CloseButton to advance to the next tip. Each tip has an "OK" or "Got It!" ActionButton. On a Win10 PC this is not a problem as you can easily move the pointer to the button but on Xbox, where MouseMode is disabled, you have to "tab" through at least 10 controls to get to the TeachingTip to dismiss it . I cannot use LightDismiss because it does not fire an event to let me open the next TT.  Does this help?

Comment: I understand your scenario, but currently `TeachingTip` cannot directly set the focus. You can detect the current device type and optimize the operation for XBOX. You can also initiate a discussion [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/new/choose) and submit a Feature Request for TeachingTip

Comment: I will submit a feature request for this. For the benefit of anyone who may need to do the same, I worked around this by checking to see if any of the teachingtips are open inside of a KeyUp event (at the page level) and advancing to the next one, if it is open and they hit the A/select button, enter or space key. Not elegant but it works, including on the Xbox.